# Tumblr RSS importer stopped working

Tags: rss, tumblr, import

I've been administering several Tumblr blogs since 2009 by means of the RSS import feature and, without any notifications, it would seem like the last time they were updated is late December 2011. It seems like the RSS import functionality is not there anymore, and all my tumblrs are now very stale.

I see Tumblr currently (2013) supports the ability to publish by email: http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/email_publishing.

I have a UNIX box, so my question is: **is there a nice script or bot that I could run to resume RSS imports?**

Answer (score 1):

Use a website called [IFTTT](https://ifttt.com), that allows you to update Tumblr via RSS.